# Computing the Gini coefficient

Tags: fitting

The data below  represents the percentiles and the share of total profit after tax made by all companies in 8 Norwegian cities given as {percentile, share of total profit}. I want to calculate The Gini coefficient of total profit. My problem is: What function is the best fit to these points?

```
data = {{0, 0}, {5, 0.006945},
 {10, 0.118745}, {15, 0.439736},
 {20, 1.026114}, {25, 1.981038}, {30,3.337514}, {35, 5.190296},
 {40, 7.623619}, {45, 10.850580}, {50, 015.027452}, {55, 20.328959}, 
 {60,27.106558}, {65, 35.805423}, {70, 46.962775},
 {75, 61.404296}, {80, 80.608454}, {85, 106.780170},
 {90, 145.138789}, {95, 211.507946}, {96, 234.027324}, {97, 263.412158},
 {98, 305.245139}, {99, 372.091182},
 {99.5, 436.940601}, {99.8, 530.097467}, {99.9, 600.113452}, {100, 1000}}
```

Comment: Could you give some more background, what function are you trying to fit?

Comment: `Interpolation[data]` will give you a function which passes exactly through all the points.

Answer (score 9):

You should provide a bit more information as @C.E. suggests.  But here is a wild guess from looking at a plot of your data.

The Gini coefficient will be the ratio of the areas A and A+B (according to [Gini coefficient](http://www.intmath.com/blog/mathematics/the-gini-coefficient-of-wealth-distribution-4187)).

```
data = {{0, 0}, {5, 0.006945}, {10, 0.118745}, {15, 0.439736}, {20, 1.026114},
   {25, 1.981038}, {30, 3.337514}, {35, 5.190296}, {40, 7.623619}, {45, 10.850580},
   {50, 015.027452}, {55, 20.328959}, {60, 27.106558}, {65, 35.805423},
   {70, 46.962775}, {75, 61.404296}, {80, 80.608454}, {85, 106.780170},
   {90, 145.138789}, {95, 211.507946}, {96, 234.027324}, {97, 263.412158},
   {98, 305.245139}, {99, 372.091182}, {99.5, 436.940601}, {99.8,[![Gini coefficient figure][2]][2] 530.097467},
   {99.9, 600.113452}, {100, 1000}};

Show[ListPlot[{data, {{0, 0}, {100, 1000}}, {{0, 0}, {100, 0}, {100, 1000}}},
  Joined -> True, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.015],
  PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  FrameLabel -> {{"", ""}, {"", Style["Gini coefficient = A/(A+B)", Bold, Large]}}],
 Graphics[Text[Style["B", Large, Bold], {95, 93}]],
 Graphics[Text[Style["A", Large, Bold], {70, 400}]]]
```

[image: Gini coefficient]

So to estimate that ratio with the data you have, maybe interpolation as @SimonWoods suggests would work:

```
ifun = Interpolation[data];
b = NIntegrate[ifun[x], {x, 0, 100}];
aPlusb = 100*1000/2;
giniCoefficient = (aPlusb - b)/aPlusb
(* 0.900825 *)
```